# Cannot be resolved as a variable (Java)

Tags: java, variables

I'm writing a program which allows a user to check in and out dogs from a kennel and I'm trying to create a search function that cycles through the array list "dogs" and then print out the name of the dog if it exists, if not you get an error printed out.

**Declared variables:**

```
public class Kennel {
private String name;
private ArrayList<Dog> dogs;
private int nextFreeLocation;
private int capacity;
private String result;
```

**Code for the search function in Kennel() :**

```
    public Dog search(String name) {
    Dog searchedFor = null;
    // Search for the dog by name
    for (Dog d : dogs) {
        if (name.equals(d.getName())) {
            searchedFor = d;
        }
    }
    /*
    if (searchedFor != null) {
        dogs.remove(searchedFor); // Requires that Dog has an equals method
        System.out.println("removed " + name);
        nextFreeLocation = nextFreeLocation - 1;
    } else
        System.err.println("cannot remove - not in kennel");
    Dog result = null;*/

    Dog result = null;

    result.equals(searchedFor);

    return result;
}
```

**And the search method in the main class (KennelDemo()):**

```
    private void searchForDog() {
    System.out.println("which dog do you want to search for");
    String name = scan.nextLine();
    Dog dog = kennel.search(name);
    if (dog != null){
        System.out.println(dog.toString());
    } else {
        System.out.println("Could not find dog: " + name);
    }
}
```

**I'm getting the error for:**

```
Dog result = null;
return result;
```

**which states:**

```
result cannot be resolved to a variable.
```

Can anyone explain this to me please? I'm new to Java so I'm extremely lost.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to assign `result` to the value of `searchedFor` in your `search` method, through invoking `equals`, which actually return `boolean` if `x` equals `argument`.

Use `=` to assign instead.

Or return `searchedFor` directly!

Comment: Awesome it's working. Think I got tripped up with how Eclipse displays errors (still shows them without saving) when I wrote that in last time. This is working, thanks a lot mate!

Answer (score 0):

result.equals(searchedFor);

Is it a condition missing out and statements or an assign statement?

If assign statement it should be

**result = searchedFor**

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
if(searchedFor != null)
  result = searchedFor
```

instead of:

```
result.equals(searchedFor);
```